# What is the word for a person who is not stupid or a fool, but deliberately trivializes things?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for a person who is not stupid or a fool, but always purposefully:

- makes fun of everything,
- passes silly comments about everything,
- responds to wise/deep questions with silly and useless answers and
- underestimates the gravity of a situation to make the situation appear light?

Comment: Depends on the context. Does the person's action(of purposefully doing things) cause others to feel hurt or happy? +ve and -ve connotations must be distinguished clearly.

Comment: While BiscuitBoy is right but taking it as a negative connotation, _sick_ might be a good word if the person is very insensitive and cracks bad jokes in a grave situation.

Comment: *Purposefully*, or *purposely* or *deliberately* ? I believe most of the time that when "*purposely*", or in your case "*purposefully*", is used, "*deliberately*" had actually been the intended meaning.

Comment: The first three characteristics line up with "immature". The fourth, less so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider **facetious**:

> If you say that someone is being facetious, you are criticizing them because they **are making humorous remarks** or saying things that they do not mean in a situation **where they ought to be serious**.

([Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/facetious))

**Impish** may also fit if you need to convey a more positive connotation:

> showing **a lack of respect or seriousness** in a way that is **amusing** rather than bad

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/impish))

Alternatively, a word like **clown** could fit:

> a comical, silly, playful person
>   *I was always the class clown*

([Oxford American Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/clown))

Answer (score 9):

[flippant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flippant) might be a good choice.

> adjective
>
> 1.
> frivolously disrespectful, shallow, or lacking in seriousness; characterized by levity

You might also consider [irreverent](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irreverent), which may carry a less negative connotation.

Comment: I agree on "irreverent", but not "flippant".  One might make a flippant remark, but that's an isolated event.  You wouldn't use it to refer to a person who does that *all the time*.  "Irreverent", on the other hand, can be used to refer to someone's general character.

Comment: I am choosing 'Flippant'.

Answer (score 1):

Joker: person who teases, kids - from the [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/joker).

Synonyms: punster, wisecracker, comedian

Answer (score 1):

> jocular
>
> fond of or characterized by joking; humorous or playful.
>   "she sounded in a jocular mood"
>   synonyms:   humorous, funny, witty, comic, comical, amusing, droll, waggish, jokey, hilarious, facetious, tongue-in-cheek, teasing, playful;
>
> [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jocular)

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably call such a person a [*smartass*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/smart-ass) or *wiseass*, meaning someone who acts as if they are above the situation, does not take things seriously, and often makes inappropriate jokes.

Another term for this is *wag* which usually refers to that one guy in a group you can always count on to make the obvious and maybe inappropriate joke.

Answer (score 1):

How about "deliberately obtuse"?

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please add a source to support your suggestion (possibly a dictionary or a book that uses these words in a way that supports your answer).

Comment: Oops.  I have a few sources and I'd post them but just now notice that the request was for one word!  Sorry.

Comment: I think it might be a good answer (no need to delete just because it's two words). The sources, however, are important, because it helps other users to see if it fits for how they want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tone of [**heedless**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/heedless) and **unaware** in there.

> Showing a reckless lack of care or attention.

Not sure it quite nails it though...

Perhaps **thoughtless** as well?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, it sounds like this person might be a [**troll**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_troll), especially if the context is discussions on the internet and the person in question is doing this to provoke others for their own amusement:

From Wikipedia (emphasis mine):

> In Internet slang, a **troll** (/ˈtroʊl/, /ˈtrɒl/) is a person who sows
>   discord on the Internet by starting arguments or upsetting people, by
>   posting inflammatory, extraneous, or off-topic messages in an online
>   community (such as a newsgroup, forum, chat room, or blog) with the
>   deliberate intent of provoking readers into an emotional response or
>   of otherwise disrupting normal on-topic discussion, often for their
>   own amusement.